# Find the number of different 6-digit numbers he would have typed

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

> Tim typed a six-digit number, but the two $1$’s he typed did not show. What appeared was $2006$. Find the number of different 6-digit numbers he would have typed.

So, I made $2$ cases:

Case $1$: The $1$'s are away from each other. By this method we have to fill $2$ spaces out of $5$. We get $$^5C_2 \times \cfrac{2!}{2!} \times \cfrac{4!}{2!}$$ As the $1$'s and the $0$'s are repeating.

Case $2$: The $1$'s are together. So, we have to select $1$ place out of $5$ places to place the $1$'s. This can be done in $$^5C_1 \times \cfrac{2!}{2!} \times \cfrac{4!}{2!}$$. So on adding the two cases, I get $450$ which is the wrong answer. Where am I making a mistake and where are the cases repeating? Please tell how to approach such problems. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the calculation for case 1? Why are you multiplying those terms (IE What are you applying the rule of product on?) Note that what appeared is 2006 in that order.

Comment: I don't think you have to account for the 0s repeating. You can think about the slots between the numbers (and at the ends) as places to choose where the 1s can go, but the individual numbers 2006 don't matter.

Comment: @CalvinLin I got my mistake thanks now I'm getting the right answer. I realized that I arranged 2006 in different orders in both cases, so the $\cfrac{4!}{2!}$ term shouldn't be there

Comment: good to see you already got the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP's confusion has been resolved:

Shortcut:

Given a $6$ digit number, with the numbers $2-0-0-6$ occurring, in that order, and with the numbers $1-1$ being inserted.

This means that $2$ places out of the possible $6$ places must be selected, for the insertion of the number $1$.

Final computation is therefore, $\binom{6}{2} = 15$.

---

To be complete, I need to demonstrate that there is a *bijection* between:

- each possible selection of $2$ places out of $6$, for insertion of the number $1$,
- and the possible number that is constructed, that features $2-0-0-6$ in that order, plus two $1$'s inserted.

Suppose that you start with six positions: x,x,x,x,x,x

Select any two of these positions to insert a $1$ - for illustration, select the 1st and 3rd postion:

1,x,1,x,x,x

Then, the string of digits $2-0-0-6$, in that order, can **then** be inserted in **exactly** one way:

1,2,1,0,0,6

The above example is for illustrative purposes only.  For each selection of $2$ places out of $6$, to insert the number $1$, there will be exactly $4$ places remaining, which allows the string $2-0-0-6$, in that order, to be placed in exactly one way.

This demonstrates that the relationship is injective.

Consider any placement of the string $2 - 0 - 0 - 6$, with the digits in that order, into a number with six positions.  Then, there must be exactly two positions remaining, for the two number $1$'s to be inserted.

This demonstrates that the relationship is surjective.

Therefore, there the relationship is a bijection.

Therefore, the number of possible numbers that can be so constructed is $\binom{6}{2} = 15.$

Comment: The question was to find the mistake in the computation of OP.

Comment: Thanks, really informative

Comment: @user Yes, and if other's had not addressed the OP's mistake, then I would not have posted my answer as is.  Note the start of my answer: "Since the OP's confusion has been resolved:".  Note further the following excerpt of a comment from the OP, that existed **before** I posted my answer: "I got my mistake thanks now I'm getting the right answer."